# Calling a function in plpgsql exception block

Tags: postgresql, exception, plpgsql

Is it possible to call a function from within the `WHEN OTHERS THEN` block?

Something like:

```
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        my_fnc('a key ID', 'Custome message', SQLERRM||' - '||SQLSTATE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you surely can:

```
t=# do $$ begin
perform 1/0;
exception when others then perform to_json(SQLERRM||' - '||SQLSTATE);
end;
$$;
DO
```

but just calling fn() is pointless, unless it performs some real action, so ritcher example:

```
t=# do $$ begin
perform 1/0;
exception when others then raise info '%', to_json(SQLERRM||' - '||SQLSTATE);
end;
$$;
INFO:  "division by zero - 22012"
DO
```

Comment: Thanks a million, "PERFORM" was what I was looking for. I had even tried "EXEC". This process is called in a multithreaded batch environment, so I log the errors to a error message table which is monitored. So I am calling an error logging function.